# Unable to install site (Drupal + CiviCRM) in french

Tags: aegir, i18n-l10n

After creating a new platform with french translations I am unable to see french words anywhere. From what I see in logs every is installed in French but when using the website nothing is...

I even tried to switch languages but nothing is working !

Any ideas ?

Thanks :D